# Angular 6 Form - Mutate Value after ValueChanges

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-forms

**My goal is to mutate the name value after every value change.** (in my case to remove all unnecessary spaces in  the name value)
I have a simple form:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    description: new FormControl(''),
});
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="name">
    <input formControlName="description">
</form>
```

Logic

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    const newName = 'some mutated name';
    this.form.patchValue({
        ...this.form.value,
        name: newName,
    });
    // triggers an infinite loop
});
```

...but this triggers an infinite loop
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the keyup event on the input:

`<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">`

Then do your string modification in the like this

`onKey(event: any) {
   // something like this
   // check event.target.value for the values and modify as needed
   this.name = newName;
 }`

Answer (score -1):

By changing one of the values in the form after the firing of valueChanges event, you are in effect forcing that same event to be called again and again and that's why you're getting the loop.

Comment: yeah, that's why I am asking  how to fix it :D